# Are these both ways okay to lower the flame in these types of gas stoves?

Tags: stove, gas, indian-cuisine

Before asking this question, I really tried to find an answer online, but I failed. Basically, we mostly have manual igniting gas stoves. If you press and turn the button on left (90 degree) and use a lighter/matchbox, it gets turned on. To lower the flame, you just turn it further a bit on **left**.

But my mom has always warned me to not to turn it so left that it becomes 180 degrees. **I wonder what happens after that**. Further, my mon never told me what happens when you keep the button between 0 degree and 90 degrees. I feel it should also lower the flame just like when the button is between 90 degree and 180 degree (i.e., turned to very left). **Because I don't see any point in the design of a button that goes from 0 degree to straight 90 degree and between them you are not supposed to get anything. And you're not supposed to do this to lower the flame**. I feel there can be a reason for it but I don't know if that's right or wrong.

I'm not sure of any these things and I can't even experiment as it's dangerous stuff.

I really felt frustrated when I googled this and I saw results like:

1. Fix your low/high frame
2. Your burners are malfunctioning. How to fix at home
3. Your gas stove buttons fix*

But I don't have any problem with my gas stove. I got really *tired* of all these. Neither I could find a video on YouTube.

I *can't* show you exact model of my gas stove as it is made by some not so known brands, but looks like most gas stoves in my neighborhood are like these. Otherwise my neighborhood people *won't* be able to know how to use our gas stoves (unless you know how to operate multiple types of stoves). Similarly, my mon also knows how to operate theirs. All are same and manual.

Even when I visited New Delhi, which is a big city than my hometown, I found same settings, but I didn't ask them how to operate, because everyone knew same things which I knew. **So I felt they will also don't know what happens between the 0 degree and 90 degree.**

[image]

[image]

Online example of similar product is [here](https://www.amazon.in/Bajaj-Popular-Stainless-Burner-Silver/dp/B01HBTRFN2/ref=asc_df_B01HBTRFN2/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397079957279&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16201904301277590542&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9298573&hvtargid=pla-501749054112&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi).

[Here](https://www.amazon.in/Butterfly-Smart-Glass-Burner-Stove/dp/B07KMC8C9B/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=sl1&tag=gasstove-21&linkId=c3485d9ba6c7fb58a937cd317d0cb5d9&language=en_IN) is a user guide, which exactly explains how to operate, except the problems and doubts I have:

[image]

Now, I don't know if you're familiar with these or not and there may be differences between western and Indian stoves, so that's why I've tried to provide enough details and images and links. Hope you'll understand my doubts.

**So, are the following ways correct to adjust the flame**?

*(a) When button is between 0° and 90°*

*(b) When button is between 90° and 180°*

*(c) When button is horizontally full turned left (180°)*

**If yes**, is it safe to keep the button between 0 degree and 90 degree *(just the way you use to lower the flame by keeping the button between 90 degree and 180 degree)*?

**If no**, what would be the reason for it? *(Asking this because I really can't believe this fact. I feel it would be a bad design. A new user is very likely to keep the button between 0 degree and 90 degree because there's generally no warning/alarm for it unless someone tells you not to do it)*

Comment: I give up. You've moved the goalposts so far that my answer just can't keep up.

Comment: Do you mean my question is off topic? If yes can you please help how to fix it?

Comment: I mean every time someone answers you, you ask another question. This is not a forum & is not threaded like one. It's not for discussion, it's for a question with several alternative answers, one of which the question asker can mark as accepted. When it becomes a chase to keep the answer matching the question, it's time for someone else to answer. I'm done.

Comment: I didn't know asking too many logical questions is bad here. I specifically asked this thing on GDSE and they said it's okay. So I had assumed it's okay: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3733/is-asking-too-many-questions-in-comments-bad-thing-here

Comment: Your comment makes me feel: 1) You can't edit your question if it contradicts the answer which is correct so far 2) You can't keep asking relevant questions in comments.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Changing the essence of your question after it has been answered & then followed up by many comments requiring further help is considered bad form. It tires people. It makes them not want to help you any more. I'm done now. Stop chasing.

Comment: Right. But only you made me realize in the comments of your answer that I couldn't ask what I was looking for. So I edited it. Which I think you didn't like. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly which type of valve they are using, but they all pretty much work the same.

You seem to be imagining the gas flow curve to look like this:

[image: Imagined Gas Flow]

The difference between the two sides is that the 0° to 90° transition is designed to move from 0% gas flow to 100% gas flow very quickly and the 90° to 180° transition is designed to perform a slow, controlled transition from 100% to the minimum flow to maintain a flame (exact amount depends on the burner design).

I've seen them designed several ways, but this is a simplified visual representation of a valve:

[image: Valve Internals]

Lighting the flame at 100% is necessary because it maximizes the area with the correct air/fuel mix to more easily initiate the flame. Once lit the flame will maintain a horizon where the air/fuel mix is correct automatically as you change the fuel pressure.

From the 90° position, turning the dial clockwise will cause the flame to abruptly turn off at some point, then the remaining rotation is used to tighten the valve so no gas leaks from the valve.

So yes, the gas flow will reduce the size of the flame as you close the valve, but it's very difficult to control the flame level on that side. The actual curve of gas flow looks more like this:

[image: Gas Flow Curve]

Comment: Thanks for the *detailed* answer. So, if you know, between 0 and 90 is dangerous or it is just designed like this and simply won't work if I try? I'm just worried it might not blast my home!

Comment: Or should I just ask the manufacturer brand itself?

Comment: It could be dangerous. If the flow is not high enough to maintain a flame, the flame will go out but the gas will continue to flow. This is likely why you mother warned you against using the lowest setting, the pressure in a gas line varies. The pressure regulator will deal with it when it is too high, but if for any of a dozen reasons the pressure is slightly lower than the rating of the range, you can lose the flame at low settings. Modern ranges are more stable because the minimum flow is higher.

Comment: It is unnecessary to contact the manufacturer, they have already provided you with the instructions for use of the unit, and those instructions take into consideration all your safety concerns (and many you haven't considered). For any device where misuse involves potentially blowing up the building it's used it, just follow the manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: Cool. One last query: So it might still turn on the flame even when the button is not at 90 and instead between 0 and 90, in case pressure is sufficient. But that's not advised. Right?

Comment: You should ALWAYS light the flame at the highest available gas flow. The only place on the dial you can guarantee you're at the highest gas flow is at the 90° position. Lighting it at another position will take longer and more gas will escape into the immediate area while you are lighting it. Once the flame catches, this can flare and injure someone.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. I could be dangerous.

Comment: But I would be surprised if the manufacturer don't warn about this thing specially, in user guide.

Comment: @Vikas product liability is a field with lots of pitfalls. Depending on local laws, listing potential abuse may have legal consequences in case someone is “inspired” by something absurd that’s mentioned in a manual and what the average user may have not thought about on their own.

Comment: @Stephie I quite didn't understand what you said. Would you please simplify it a bit? :)

Comment: @vikas, the legal reasons for disclaimers or lack thereof are not really within the scope of cooking. Every jurisdiction will be different, but generally speaking if you use the product in a way inconsistent with the manufacturer's instructions, you take on the liability for that misuse. We have already explained the engineering realities that the instructions reflect. If you're interested in the intricacies of Indian product liability law, I recommend you ask a followup question on law.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LightBender oh. By liability you mean I would be responsible (in general case like you said) for misuse even when they didn't warn in manufacturer's instructions?

Comment: @Vikas ...yes...